# What function does the comma serve in the salutation of a letter, and when did it come about?

Tags: history, formality, linguistics, letter-writing

In a letter, we say "Dear Alexthecampbell," before starting the body.  We then capitalize the first letter of the next sentence.

Since the salutation functions like a header and isn't part of the next sentence, why is there a need for a comma at all, and how did this start?

Comment: I meant to say "isn't part of the next sentence"

Comment: ... Now you have.

Comment: The salutation is a sentence fragment (cf 'To ...') or even less.  A full stop would be too heavy-duty, and some feel that some separator is necessary between the salutation and the message. In fact, when a new line is used for the first sentence, this is sufficient separation, and many drop the traditional comma.

Comment: I don't know the history and so I wouldn't presume to answer, but I would think that the salutation *was* part of the first sentence and at some point a custom arose to off set that salutation.  Grammatically we'd expect "Dear John" to be part of a longer sentence, like in, "**My God,** why have you forsaken me?"

Comment: As always, the best criteria for comma usage should depend on a reading: if you feel the need for a breath or pause, put a comma. Apart from that, is this for a personal friend, or business acquaintance?///It's convention, that's all.

Comment: Note that the salutation likely was not originally placed on a separate line.

Comment: @HotLicks Interesting...do you mean in this instance, or in the original usages dating back into Older English . Maybe there is something to consider here....like a parenthetical comma.

Comment: @Cascabel - I mean parchment was relatively precious at one time, and people would not have wasted it with needless "whitespace".

Comment: @HotLicks _de acuerdo_...that's what I thought.

Comment: @HotLicks Not just parchment, writing paper and envelpes were so expensive until the middle to late 19th century that people wrote letters [on the cross](https://www.lonetester.com/2016/02/cross-writing-what-is-it-and-how-do-you-read-it/) which meant that each page was written on twice, once in the normal way and then continued with the paper turned through ninety degrees. This was done to save paper. A simpler version which saved less paper was to continue the letter around the margins of the paper.

Comment: Conventionally, there is/ there has been a comma after the salutation. If it was dropped by 'some' users, does it change the (standardized) convention?  2) Salutation is related not just to the first sentence after it, but to the whole body of the letter. Without a comma, it looks like a domesticated dog without belt. However as @Cascabel said, those who feel the need for a breath or pause, put a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Using a comma before or after naming the person who your speech is directed at, just indicates that direction.
Like:

Hey, John, how’s it going?

It is used to direct speech and guide the reader to understand who the message is intended for.

I imagine it was always used.

The use of white space— beginning the body of the letter on a separate line— may simply be to make it easier to make out the greeting from the body, and to create a nicer appearance easier on the eye.

Answer (score 0):

The comma after a salutation is a 'vocative comma'. It is used to indicate a shift from vocative case to nominative case.

Its oral use no doubt predates the history of punctuation.